# How to transform my sparse count data into normal distribution?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, biostatistics, count-data, sparse

I am running glm on beetle counts data. My predictors are environmental variables and my response variable is the number of beetles.

I ran three glms:

1. The response variable $Y_1$ is the total number of beetles.
2. The response is a subset of $Y_1$ ($Y_2$).
3. The response is also a subset of $Y_1$ ($Y_3=Y_1-Y_2$). In this $Y_3$, there are many zeros in my distribution, so the residual distribution is very far from normal.

How can I transform $Y_3$ to meet the assumption of normality?
Does anyone have an equivalent robust non-parametric test?

Comment: If your outcome is a count is there any reason why you are avoiding Poisson regression?

Comment: Or negative binomial regression, etc...

Comment: thanks for your answers. I log-transformed to normalize my response variable and diagnosed the model by checking for residuals normality... what is wrong. I will do a simple one glm(Y~X, family=poisson) and check for the goodness-of-fit the model.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a Poisson regression (or in case of overdispersion, maybe negative binomial or quasi-Poisson regression). There is no assumption of normality in those models, so no need for transformations. See [Normality requirements for GLM and GEE models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/513088/normality-requirements-for-glm-and-gee-models)